# Trying to add webjob to Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-webjobs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-webjobssdk

I had a webapp already configured for CI/CD to a UAT environment.  I added a webjob that works fine (did all the 'add as webjob' and 'publish as Azure webjob' steps).  I see my webjob via the azure portal and it logs messages in my dev environment.

So then I checked in my code and promoted to UAT slot of my production environment.  The first attempt failed b/c there was > 1 zip so I modified my wildcard to pick up only my webapp.zip.  I took this as a good sign that it found my webjob code.  However, nothing additional seemed to happen - the webapp deployed fine but no sign of the webjob.

From googling around it sounds as though my webjob should be magically picked up and installed based on the 2 json files (webjobs-list.json in the webapp & settings.job in the webjob) but it is not.  In fact I don't even see an App_Data folder in the console of the UAT slot.

Am I supposed to add an additional block into the release for this that searches the webjob zip? That makes sense to me but I keep seeing people saying NOT to do that.  Please advise!

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I'm having a similar problem...have a single VS Solution, with an MVC Project, and multiple WebJob projects.  How do I modify the Release Pipeline in Azure DevOps to deploy the WebJob project artifacts (zip files) ?